# How to form a nested JSON object from an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, algorithm, recursion

I have a path(as a string) like

> A/B/C/D

.
I want to represent it as a JSON object as follows :

```
{
   A:{
      B:{
         C:D
      }
   }
}
```

Now lets say I add a path

> A/B/C/X

then the JSON should look like

```
{
   A:{
      B:{
         C:[D,X]
      }
   }
}
```

So what I do is when I get the path, I split it and store in an array as follows

```
var struct = {};
var path = $scope.path.split("/"); //assuming $scope.path holds the path  
for(var i =0;i<path.length-1;i++)
    {
        struct[path[i]] = path[i+1];
    }
```

However this leads to json as `{A: "B", B: "C", C: "D"}`. 
How do I fix this? Is there a recursive way to do this?

EDIT : My previous schema would lead to error. As KevinB suggested, I am updating the schema to something like [{name: 'A', children: [{name: 'B', children: []}]}]

Comment: You can't have two identical keys in an object, so you will never get `C: D` and `C: X` in the `B` object, `C` would need to be converted to an array of `[D,X]`, or `B` to be an array of `[{C:D},{C:X}]`

Comment: *"Is there a recursive way to do this?"* Yes, iterate over the path, on each iteration go one level deeper into the object until you're through the whole path. However, first you have to come up with a schema that actually works, per the previous comment.

Comment: Fixed my question for the discrepancy.

Comment: Your updated schema, how then would you represent /A/B/C/D/E? or /A/Z?

Comment: @KevinB Could you write a snippet to do the same?

Comment: Was thinking maybe a more normalized structure, such as `[{name: 'A', children: [{name: 'B', children: []}]}]`

Comment: @KevinB yeah that sounds like a good schema. Could you show an implementation for that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, take a look at this function which was created for that (i'm the author, by the way):

https://github.com/DiegoZoracKy/make-object-path

The code is:

```
    var makeObjectPath = function(_src, _path, _val) {

    var src = _src,
        path = _path,
        val = _val;

    if (arguments[0] instanceof Array || typeof(arguments[0]) == 'string') {
        src = {};
        path = arguments[0];
        val = arguments[1] || null;
    }

    path = (typeof(path) == 'string') ? path.split('.') : path;

    var o = src;
    var currentO = o;
    for (var i in path) {
        currentO[path[i]] = (i != path.length - 1) ? currentO[path[i]] || {} : (val) ? val : {};
        currentO = currentO[path[i]];
    }
    return o;
}
```

And to use it:

```
makeObjectPath('root.parent.child', 'someValue');

// Output:

{
    "root":{
        "parent":{
            "child":"someValue"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But if I have more than one value of say child or parent, this function will not be able to handle that. I need to create a directory structure